# Regex Extract a capture group based on a parent capture group

Tags: regex, grafana

I'm trying to format a drop down variable in Grafana in which the values are structured email addresses that I need to set a portion to the named capture group  and place the entire email address in the named capture group .  The general details of what I'm trying to do is explained on the [Grafana Support page](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.3/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#filter-and-modify-using-named-text-and-value-capture-groups).  What I'm looking to do is take the values in a variable query and modify them in the `regex` area to accomplish the following.

With the query result values of:

```
development+info@example.com
production+errors@example.com
production+warnings@example.com
```

I would like the regex to produce two named capture groups text and value.

```
<text>    |     <value>
info      |     development+info@example.com
errors    |     production+errors@example.com
warnings  |     production+warnings@example.com
```

The regex `(\S+\+)?(?<text>\S+)@.*|(?<value>.*)` only seems to set the `<text>` capture group.

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: When you have alternatives, only one of them can match at a time, so you can't get both capture groups. I think you want nested groups, not alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<value>[^@\s]+\+(?<text>[^@\s+]*)@.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DMPjnJ/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<value>` - Group "value" start:

  - `[^@\s]+` - one or more chars other than `@` and whitespace
  - `\+` - a literal `+` char (needs escaping, or it would be a quantifier)
  - `(?<text>` - Group "text" start:

    - `[^@\s+]*` - zero or more chars other than `@`, whitespace and `+`
  - `)` - end of Group "text"
- `@` - a `@` char
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `)` - end of Group "value".

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmar pointed out in the comments, you want nested groups instead of alternatives.

This will work in Grafana:

`/(?<value>\S+\+(?<text>.*)@.*)/`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Loki, you have to use LogQL instead of Prometheus QL as can be seen [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/query_examples/#examples-that-aid-in-security-evaluation), e.g.

```
{job="security"}
    != "grafana_com"
    |= "session opened"
    != "sudo: "
    |regexp "(^(?P<user>\\S+ {1,2}){11})"
    | line_format "USER = {{.user}}"
```